# Accidentally created another root user. How to delete or change permissions?

Tags: root, user-management, adduser, uid

I need a non-root user to do certain (safe) things. I didn't pay attention, and used `useradd -ou 0 -g 0 new_user_name`, which gave root permissions to the user. It also has the same UID of 0.

Before I do something stupid, can anyone help me on how to delete this user, or simply change the permissions/UID? I already discovered what happens with pkill. Hahaha.

Comment: `man userdel`? --- if you want to be on the safe side (but I hope the tool will have no problem with duplicated UIDs) you can backup `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow/`,  and the corresponding group files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userdel` has an option `-f` to force removal. `userdel` would probably just delete the `passwd` entry and home directory, without affecting the actual root account.

To be safer, I might be inclined to hand-edit the password file to remove the entry for your new root user, then hand-remove new root user's home directory. You may have a command on your system named `nano`, which lets you safely edit `/etc/passwd` in a text editor.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/804210/how-can-i-delete-root-users

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to log in as that user so I can operate as a non-root user.

Comment: What exactly do you want? With sudo adduser nameoftheuser you create a user without any admin privilage. Just add it to suddoers file in /etc/sudoers to gain that privilages. Stop messinf with root accs, this is the way easier and safer.

Comment: I added a user named "hal" just to initially try it out. After that, I type su - hal, and get "No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ 
"